# What is $\lim\limits_{k\rightarrow \infty} \frac{k}{k^{2}+1}$

Tags: limits

How do you evaluate the following limit?

$$\lim\limits_{k\rightarrow \infty} \frac{k}{k^{2}+1}$$

Comment: look at what happens when you divide by $k$ in the numerator and denominator

Comment: $$\lim\limits_{k\rightarrow \infty} \frac{\frac{k}{k^{2}}}{1+\frac{1}{k^{2}}}$$?

Comment: One doesn't solve a limit; one evaluates a limit. ;-)) And $\frac{k}{k^2+1}<\frac1k$ should help here.

Comment: As Peter Woolfitt suggested,
$$ \lim\limits_{k\to\infty} \dfrac{k}{k^2+1} = \lim\limits_{k\to\infty} \dfrac{1}{k+\frac{1}{k}} = \cdots $$
Or you can evaluate the limit using L'Hopital:
$$ \lim\limits_{k\to\infty} \dfrac{k}{k^2+1} = \lim\limits_{k\to\infty} \dfrac{1}{2k} = \cdots $$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll be rigorous here. Notice that
$$ 0 \leq \frac{k}{k^2 + 1} \leq \frac{k}{k^2} = k^{-1}
$$
since $k^2 + 1 \geq k^2$.

and
$$ \lim_{k \to \infty} k^{-1} = 0, \lim_{k \to \infty} 0 = 0
$$
so by the squeeze theorem,
$$ \lim_{k \to \infty} \frac{k}{k^2 + 1} = 0
$$